Why did Hashem wait three days to reveal to Avraham the exact place of the Akeida?
In Parshas Vayeira, it says that Hashem revealed to Avraham the exact place of the Akeidah on the third day of Avraham's journey. Rashi explains that Hashem waited three days in order to counter the claims of the Goyim that Avraham didn't have enough time to think about what he was about to do. With three days to ponder, he had a clear mind. My question is, what is significant about three days; would not have been one day enough to counter their claims?
Maybe these three days have some connection to the third day that Hashem visited Avraham at the beginning of the Parsha?

Uncertainty is part of the test. 3 is used as a chazaka and perhaps 3 days is showing an even greater than normal level of uncertainty

Maybe the three days are an incidental by product of the required location.

According to Bereshis Rabba 56:1 there is a merit of the 3rd day, since the Torah was given on the 3rd day, while Rabbi Levi thinks it's the opposite, Avraham's Akkeida set the 3 days significance:

“On the third day, Abraham lifted his eyes, and saw the place from a distance” (Genesis 22:4). “On the third day, Abraham lifted his eyes” – it is written: “He will revive us after two days; on the third day, He will lift us, and we will live before Him” (Hosea 6:2). “On the third day” of the tribes, as it is written: “Joseph said to them on the third day, [do this and you shall live]” (Genesis 42:18). “On the third day” of the spies [sent by Joshua], as it is stated: “You shall hide there three days, […and then go on your way]” (Joshua 2:16). “On the third day” of the giving of the Torah, as it is stated: “It was on the third day” (Exodus 19:16). “On the third day” of Jonah, as it is written: “Jonah was in the innards of the fish three days and three nights” (Jonah 2:1). “On the third day” of those who ascended [to the Land of Israel] from the Diaspora [with Ezra], as it is written: “We remained there three days” (Ezra 8:32). “On the third day” of the revival of the dead, as it is written: “He will revive us after two days; on the third day, He will lift us” (Hosea 6:2). “On the third day” of Esther: “It was on the third day; Esther donned royal raiments [and stood in the courtyard of the king’s house]” (Esther 5:1). She wore the royal raiments of her ancestor’s household. By what merit [did Esther succeed in her mission on the third day]? The Rabbis and Rabbi Levi, the Rabbis say: It was by the merit of the third day on which the Torah was given, as it is stated: “It was on the third day, when it was morning” (Exodus 19:16). Rabbi Levi said: It was due to the merit of the third day of Abraham our patriarch, as it is stated: “On the third day, [Abraham lifted his eyes].”
“And saw the place from a distance” – what did he see? He saw a cloud attached to the mountain. He said: ‘It appears that this is the place where the Holy One blessed be He told me to sacrifice my son.’

In other words, there were many events in the Jewish history that happened on the 3rd day, all of them are tied to either the Sinai revelation or Akkeidah (according to R. Levi). 3 days is usually sufficient time for complete preparation for undertaking an important mission (argument, counter-argument, resolution). Hashem made sure that all of them were done with clear mind and sufficient readiness. Just like Jewish people had to prepare themselves for Matan Torah so they had to prepare in each of the events presented by the midrash.
